# SprinBoot Authentication with both username and password

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

Using Springboot security i need to look for user and password during the authentication phase.
In Userdatails' loaduserbyname method, I only know username.
Is there a way to be able to obtain the password and then perform the search with both the username and the password?
The database I have to authenticate with has a duplicate username but different passwords

Comment: Show some code and it also sounds like the real issue is the "duplicate username". Try first altering the username field to be unique in the db table.

Comment: I agree with you Tashi! the most logical solution is to standardize the datable so as not to have duplications in the username

Answer (score 0):

The User Details are the wrong Objekt.

You have to implement a custom AuthenticationProvider. This will have access to username and password. You can use those to query the DB.

Here is an example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider.